# Loop database rows and copy field into another field

Tags: python

MySQL DATABASE TABLE "accounts"
[image: My database example]

How I can make a script in Python that loops all the rows in that table (accounts) and copy the value from row `id` to row `name` if row `name` is empty?

After some reading I managed to get some code:

```
import mysql.connector


db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    database="mydatabase"
)

db_pointer = db.cursor()

db_pointer.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts")

result = db_pointer.fetchall()

for x in result:
    print(x)
```

How can I read for example, value of "email" in each row? Like:

```
for x in result:
    print(x.email)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: my attempt was clearly in the question... for x in result:
    print(x.email)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should give you a working example for what you are looking for.

```
import mysql.connector


db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    passwd="pass",
    database="mydatabase"
)

db_pointer = db.cursor()

db_pointer.execute("SELECT id, ISNULL(name, '') FROM accounts")

result = db_pointer.fetchall()

for x in result:
    #assuming that the SELECT query is returned properly x[0] is the id and x[1] is the name
    if (x[1] == ""):
       #we also assume that id is a primary key
       db_pointer2 = db.cursor()
       db_pointer2.execute("INSERT INTO accounts SET name = '" + x[0] + "' WHERE id = '" + x[0] + "'")
```

Each query result line is an array and each member of the array is accessed with

```
array[index]
```

method.